# Is there a way to do lazy loading in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've built, maintain and continually improve a website for an insanely complex fantasy football league I'm in where GMs have $130 of salary cap a year, players all have a starting salary value and may be signed to longterm deals using that initial salary amount as a starting point for subsequent years.

There's a lot more to it, but that's enough for what I need info on. Each GM has a team page that shows all the players he has on his team/signed to longterm deals along with some other roster breakdowns, historical payout information, draft rosters (basically a drag-and-drop sortable "shopping list" of players to keep an eye on), pending/completed/rejected trade requests, and private messages along with a lot of other information:

[image: (this is only PART of that Roster tab...there's far too much to fit into a single screenshot)]

As you might imagine, this is an INSANE amount of information to load for each team. Upgrading to Ruby 2.1.2 alleviated a LOT of issues (page load times dropped from ~7 seconds to ~3 seconds on average), but there's still more that could be done.

Is there any way to make my 93-line teams#show action load lazily? So, like, for instance, the Roster and all associated variables would load when going to a team page since that's the first/default tab. But then the Payouts, Draft Rosters, Trades and Messages variables wouldn't fire their queries to set the variables until each of their tabs was activated? I've been trying to find anything I can about Rails lazy loading but I've had no luck at all finding anything even remotely close to what I want to do.

Comment: Couldn't you not render these pages and only render them via Ajax when the tab is clicked?

Comment: I don't know. Could I? Wouldn't all the instance variables for the show action still be set regardless of whether or not the tabs are loaded? I'm not concerned about the front end lazy loading, I'm concerned about the show action only loading the instance variables necessary for the view(s) that has(have) been activated.

Comment: You can create one controller action per tab. You have your `#show` action goading everything today. You would have a #show loading only the main page and the roster tab. Then you you create the following actions: `#payouts, #draft_rosters, #trades, #mailbox`. Each of these action would have it's own view with just the tab content. Then use ajax tab loading: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax To load the content lazily when the tab os clicked. I'm a bit in a hurry, but I'll try to elaborate that better later

Comment: I actually got to thinking about doing this last night but wasn't sure if it was possible and, if it is, how to properly go about doing it. Would each one have its own draft_rosters.html.erb, mailbox.html.erb, etc file that would get loaded into their respective tabs?

Comment: Yep! Exactaly. And them each tab would have it's own instance variables, because they would be loaded on it's own action

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded sooner...haven't had any chance to work on this yet, but would you mind making that comment the answer so I can accept it and get this close + you your points? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one controller action per tab.

So you have something like this. The main page would be the `users#show` action. That would render the main layout and the tabpanel  (with the roster tab).

Then create one action per tab. So you would have:`users#payouts`, `users#draft_rosters`, `users#trades` `users#mailbox`

Those actions can be loaded via ajax only when the tab is clicked for the first time: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Each tab would have it's own html.erb file. This file is the content of the page.

This way each tab has it's own instance variables that are only loaded when the tab is clicked.